# Could a content type be corrupt?

Tags: 7, nodes

I just update a site from Drupal 7.14 to Drupal 7.15 and made some other modules updates.

One of the content I have created in the site is **Inmuebles**

The site have around 200 nodes of the Inmueble type. All of them are shown fine. But if I tried to **edit** them I get a blank page (nothing at all).

I tried to **Edit** the content type Inmueble itself and I get a blank page.

I tried to **Manage the Fields** and I get a blank page.

I have no problems with other content types, just with this one.

I guess this content type has a mis-configuration but I see no way to fix it if I can't access to modify it.

If I delete the content type because I will delete the nodes as well, then I can't do that.

What can I do? I have Drush installed, just in case it helps to fix this.

**UPDATE**

**Found the problem (but not the source of the problem)**
*It was a problem of memory size. I had to set the memory size to 512 to get the content type loaded. But this is not normal anyway. The page takes 1 minute to load... and why does this content type need this much memory to work fine. How can I fix this?*

I enabled  `Display query log` , `Display memory usage` and `Display memory usage` 
Now if I edit a node I get this summary report:

> Executed 731 queries in 555.96 ms. Queries exceeding 5 ms are
>   highlighted. Page execution time was 3058.65 ms. Memory used at:
>   devel_boot()=2.08 MB, devel_shutdown()=135.13 MB, PHP peak=137.25 MB.

Comment: Enable error reporting using http://drupal.org/node/158043 and post the errors you see in blank page here... That will help to find the problem...

Comment: Drupal 14 to 15 ? Guess I overslept again. Time to go back to the past.

Comment: Actually 7.14 to 7.15 i guess :-) Edited !

Comment: yeah I meant 7.14.

Comment: found the source of the problem. please see my update at the bottom of the question.

Comment: I am having a similar problem. were you able to get figure out the solution for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export all the nodes of content type "Inmuebles" with the drush command

```
drush -u 1 ne-export --type=inmuebles
```

Then maybe try deleting the content type and creating it again.

Although it doesnt make sense for a content type to just get corrupt, maybe if you check your error reports or apache log you will get a better look.

Comment: Importing is again a pain and if any references to that content will be lost like comments and node references...So deleting a content type or nodes is not an option !!

Comment: If you have any custom theme installed, try switching to Drupal "Bartick" theme and check if its working.

Comment: Node export should preserve noderefs and comments if you have the proper sub-modules enabled.  You can always take a backup, try this method, and restore the backup if it doesn't work.

Comment: I have Bartik enabled, I found what is the problem but not the source of the problem. Pls see my updates at the bottom of the question